# Dictionary from another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dictionary with IDs and counts:

```
  items_count = {
    '1111:271': 111, 
    '1111:190': 3, 
    '1231:106': 13, 
    '1211:104': 111, 
    '1111:201': 9
    }
```

Key is "category":"id". I want to separate category and put it in another dictionary like:

```
items_count2 = {
    '1111': {'271': 111, '190': 3, '201': 0},
    '1231': {'106': 13}, 
    '1211': {'104': 111}
    }
```

but when I do this

```
items_count2 = {k.split(':')[0]: {k.split(':')[1]: v} for k, v in items_count}
```

I get error
"ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

please help to understand, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: iterating over `items_count` goes through keys. If you want to go over (k, v) tuples you need to use `items_count.items()`

Comment: But I need to separate key, not value

Comment: Did you at least try my suggestion? `in items_count` gives you keys and you are treating them as a tuple in `for k, v` part.

Comment: @matszwecja you are wrong that doesn t fix anything try to solve it you'll see.

Comment: @Synthase I tried, and it most certainly solves the `ValueError` problem. The fact that there are other issues in the code doesn't make me wrong.

Comment: @matszwecja it solves the value error for sure, but check out my answer there was indeed another thing behind.

Comment: @Synthase And that's why I said it as a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first your suggestion should be:

```
items_count2 = {k.split(':')[0]: {k.split(':')[1]: v} for k, v in items_count.items()}
```

But this won't be working neither, cause you have multiple k, v per sub-dictionary.

So below is a way to do, without using dict comprehension:

```
dct = {
    '1111:271': 111, 
    '1111:190': 3, 
    '1231:106': 13, 
    '1211:104': 111, 
    '1111:201': 9
}

# Initialize your new dict
new_dct = {k.split(':')[0]: {} for k in dct} # Or k in dct.keys()

# Loop through old dict
for k, v in dct.items():
    # Set value to top > sub key in new dict
    new_dct[k.split(':')[0]][k.split(':')[1]] = v
    
print(new_dct)
```

Output:

```
{'1111': {'271': 111, '190': 3, '201': 9}, '1231': {'106': 13}, '1211': {'104': 111}}
```

Comment: a little correction, if you dont mind ;) 
new_dct = {k.split(':')[0]: {} for k in dct}

Comment: @Les_Grosman I've done it. Although I think that syntax is the reason why you got confused at first with for k, v in dct :)

Answer (score 1):

```
items_count2  = {}
for k, v in items_count.items():  
  t = items_count2.get(k.split(':')[0],{})
  t[k.split(':')[1]] = v
  items_count2[k.split(':')[0]] = t
```

output:

```
{'1111': {'190': 3, '201': 9, '271': 111},
 '1211': {'104': 111},
 '1231': {'106': 13}}
```

```
{k.split(':')[0]: {k.split(':')[1]: v} for k, v in items_count.items()}
```

will not give the desired solution because if the key already exists it will be replaced by the current one. So your values will always be a directory of single keys.

Comment: I didn't downvote anybody but will accept another solution due to post time and code length. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up a dictionary with the [needed keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71050003/14277722) is a clearer solution. But if you want to avoid looping, splitting and indexing twice you can create the needed keys on the fly with [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault).

```py
items_count = {
    '1111:271': 111, 
    '1111:190': 3, 
    '1231:106': 13, 
    '1211:104': 111, 
    '1111:201': 9
}

items_count2 = {}
for k,v in items_count.items():
    s1, s2 = k.split(':')
    items_count2.setdefault(s1, {})[s2] = v
items_count2
```

Output

```
{'1111': {'190': 3, '201': 9, '271': 111},
 '1211': {'104': 111},
 '1231': {'106': 13}}
```